# Javascript - .toJSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am a newbie to JSON & hence I am not sure what `$.toJSON(params)` means.

Please explain what this does.

Comment: it's probably some JS library's code to convert something to JSON format..

Comment: http://www.json.org/json2.js , This is what you should be using when dealing with JSON.

Comment: @Anders: page not found.

Comment: @ADC https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It could be this [jQuery plugin](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-json/)

```
var myObj = {};
myObj.propA = "a";
myObj.propB = "b";
myObj.propC = "c";
var jsonString = $.toJSON(myObj); // same as jQuery.toJSON(myObj)
// output:  '{ "propA" : "a", "propB" : "b", "propC" : "c" }'
```

Comment: Most likely is this plugin, but why you would use that plugin over `json2.js` I don't know....

Answer (score 5):

See: http://www.json.org/js.html

> A JSON stringifier goes in the opposite direction, converting JavaScript data structures into JSON text. JSON does not support cyclic data structures, so be careful to not give cyclical structures to the JSON stringifier.
>
> ```
> var myJSONText = JSON.stringify(myObject, replacer);
> ```
>
> If the `stringify` method sees an object that contains a `toJSON` method, it calls that method, and stringifies the value returned. This allows an object to determine its own JSON representation.
>
> The stringifier method can take an optional array of strings. These strings are used to select the properties that will be included in the JSON text.
>
> The stringifier method can take an optional `replacer` function. It will be called after the `toJSON` method (if there is one) on each of the values in the structure. It will be passed each key and value as parameters, and this will be bound to object holding the key. The value returned will be stringified.

So if you have a `$.toJSON()` method, it could be a [badly implemented function](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-json/) to "stringify", or it could be a method that returns the "JSON Representation" of `$`

Answer (score 1):

It passes the variable `params` as an argument to the method named `toJSON` attached to the object stored in the ([unhelpfully named](http://blog.dorward.me.uk/2009/02/19/the-dollar-function-must-die.html)) variable `$`.

Based on the name, it probably converts the contents of the `params` variable to a String formatted according to the [JSON specification](http://json.org/).